# How to use Firebase authStateChanges with foreign information?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am developing a mobile app similar to canvas. It has a welcome page, where users select their respective school and then are prompted with a google sign in button. Once signed in, Firebase takes over whether I used the `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` to signify where the user is logged in or not. However, the `authStateChanges()` only returns `User? user`. But I have a `_userFromFirebase` model which requires the school ID that I get during the login screen to store information inside the school collection in firebase.

```dart
CurrentUser? _userFromFirebase(User? user, String schoolUID) {
    return user != null
        ? CurrentUser(uid: user.uid, schoolUID: schoolUID)
        : null;
  }

  Stream<CurrentUser?> get user {
    return _auth
        .authStateChanges()
        .map((User? user) => _userFromFirebase(user, '6NRta<schools_id>LxiJ')); <--- here
  }

Future<dynamic> signInWithGoogle(String schoolID) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? account = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication auth = await account!.authentication;
      final AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: auth.idToken, accessToken: auth.accessToken);
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      CurrentUser? currentUser = _userFromFirebase(result.user, schoolID);

      bool userExists = await DatabaseService(user: currentUser)
          .checkIfUserExists(currentUser!.uid);
      if (!userExists) {
        DatabaseService(user: currentUser)
            .userCreationData(result.user, schoolID);
      }
      return currentUser;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

Above are the two function in my AuthService that get the `authStateChanges()` from when the user logs in, and the google sign in function.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<CurrentUser?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: const Wrapper(),
        theme: ThemeData(
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            primaryColor: MyTheme.kPrimaryColor,
            colorScheme: ThemeData()
                .colorScheme
                .copyWith(secondary: MyTheme.kAccentColor)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my `main.dart` file which has the stream provider and looks for the auth changes.

```dart
Center(child: GoogleSignInButton(onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signInWithGoogle(widget.schoolID);
                if (context.mounted) {
                  Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                }
              })),
```

Finally this is my google sign in button, which follows the user selecting the school with which we get the `widget.schoolID` and is passed during the google sign in.

To summarize, my provider function only has access `User? user`. I also want to access my schoolID, which is where all my Firebase Firestore information is saved. If you did notice, I manually added the school id for now, but I need to be updated dynamically. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Stream** of current user's information stored in **FireStore**.

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> userInfo() {
  return fireStore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).snapshots();
}
```

and this stream works like **authStateChanges()** instead of User it looks for fireStore collection:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: userInfo(), //using the stream
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return const HomePage();
        } else {
          return const LoginPage();
        }
      } else {
        return const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```